# Parsing JSON with C# and adding results to winform combobox

Tags: c#, json, winforms, combobox

I am trying to create a WinForm application that parses a json file to populate a combobox.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"Id":0,"Name":"default","Option":"default","Description":"default","OtherDescription":"default"}
```

I've created a class called Incident having properties that will be filled with the json information:

```
    public class Incident
{
    public Incident(int id, string name, string option, string description, string otherDescription)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Option = option;
        Description = description;
        OtherDescription = otherDescription;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And a list a class IncidentsList:

```
    public class IncidentsList
{
    public List<Incident> Incidents = new List<Incident>();

}
```

For some reason I am unable to populate the combobox items with the name of the incident.

Here is the entire code, any help will be highly appreciated:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        var incident = new Incident(0, "default", "default", "default", "default");
        // Convert object to Json
        var strResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incident);
        // Write values as Json file
        File.WriteAllText(@"configuration.json", strResultJson);
        // Read values from file
        var strReadJson = File.ReadAllText(@"configuration.json");  
        // Convert to Json Object
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IncidentsList>(strReadJson);

        foreach (var option in x.Incidents.Select(p => p.Name))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(option);
        }

    }

}

public class Incident
{
    public Incident(int id, string name, string option, string description, string otherDescription)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Option = option;
        Description = description;
        OtherDescription = otherDescription;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherDescription { get; set; }
}

public class IncidentsList
{
    public List<Incident> Incidents = new List<Incident>();

}
```

Comment: Why are you unable to? Does it return an error or does it not fill the combobox at all? Try stepping through your code in Form1_Load() using your IDE's debugger (if available) to examine what data is being generated

Comment: Hi, there is no compile error, the combobox is not filling at all.

Comment: x object seems to have the value of {Json.IncidentsList}

Comment: @MihaiDumitru i hope this link help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/combobox-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: p.Name = error CS0103: The name 'p' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You create an object, serialize it, write out the text, then read it back, deserialize for use in the CBO.  Why?  Why not use the first object?  You should also look into databinding

Comment: @Plutonix I think it's going to simulate a problem. to solve it

Comment: @Plutonix I have in mind the option that the user will be able to create an incident itself from the Winform, save it to the file and after the application is restarted it will automatically read the file and populate the fileds. Of course this needs more forms to be added, but will do in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are serializing a single incident and trying to deserialize it into a list of incidents.
Secondly - i am not 100% sure, but i think -  Json needs an empty constructor in the incident to deserialize, because it sets the public properties after creating an empty object.

So add your first incident to a list and then serialize that.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1() 
  {
    InitializeComponent();

  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //
    var incident = new Incident(0, "default", "default", "default", "default");
    var list = new List<Incident>();
    list.Add(incident);
    // Convert object to Json
    var strResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    // Write values as Json file
    File.WriteAllText(@"configuration.json", strResultJson);
    // Read values from file
    var strReadJson = File.ReadAllText(@"configuration.json");  
    // Convert to Json Object
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Incident>>(strReadJson);

    foreach (var option in x.Select(p => p.Name))
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(option);
    }

  }

}

public class Incident
{

  public Incident()
  {
  }
  public Incident(int id, string name, string option, string description, string otherDescription)
  {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    Option = option;
    Description = description;
    OtherDescription = otherDescription;
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Option { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string OtherDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MihaiDumitru Please Accept this answer as correct answer.

Comment: Found out just a few weeks ago, that you could also have a constructor with all properties named, which could get quite a lot, depending on the class/struct. But it will work also (with NewtwonSoft.Json).